# Why recursion change result?

Tags: python, tail-recursion, doctest

I was checking out [doctest](http://docs.python.org/library/doctest.html) and copied the factorial example to my editor. Since using recursion felt more functional programming, I felt like changing the example like this;

```
def factorial(n):
    # ... omitted
    if n+1 == n:  # catch a value like 1e300
        raise OverflowError("n too large")

    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return factorial(n  - 1) * n
```

After this change, one of the tests failed;

```
Failed example:
    factorial(30.0)
Expected:
    265252859812191058636308480000000L
Got:
    2.6525285981219103e+32
```

What is the reason of this difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try running with `factorial(30)` instead of `factorial(30.0)`.  floating point addition isn't exact like integer addition, so you'll start seeing errors after a while.

Consider:

```
>>> 1e20 + 1 == 1e20 #True
```

This is because you don't have enough *precision* (bits) to store both of those numbers uniquely.  (a typical python float has 64 bits meaning you have 2**64 unique combinations -- somewhere around `1.84e19` options.  However, the maximum size for a python float is `sys.float_info.max` which is about `1.8e308` on most systems, so there is no way to store each integral value uniquely -- especially when you consider that floats can hold a lot more than just integer values)

Personally, I would just cast the value of n to an integer inside your factorial function since factorial is only defined for integers -- possibly checking to make sure that `abs(int(n) - n) < 1e-5` or something to that effect.

Comment: Why doesn't this throw an OverflowError? Ah! I got it, it is throwing an error on **n**.

Comment: Python has long integers which are arbitrary precision.

Answer (score 1):

The number you're entering is a float. Since you're not converting it to an int you'll get a float in the output.